# How to add key value pair in nsmutable array?

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

i am storing my data in coredata. i stored 50 cityname in coredata. now when i fetch that data i just got value means city name its looks like {Abana,
    "Abdipa\U015fa",
    Abide,
    "Ac\U0131g\U00f6l",
    "Ac\U0131payam",
    "Adakl\U0131",
    Adalar,} but i want it like {city:Abdipa,City:Abide,City : Adalar}

here is my code for storing city in nsmutable array

```
 if let results = try moc.executeFetchRequest(personfetch) as? [City] {
            for user in results  {

                 firstNames.addObject(user.city!)
            }
        }
```

but its storing only value. so how can i save its with key value?

Answer (score -1):

add nsmutable dictionary in nsmutable array like this

```
contactArray.addObject(NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys:"1","id",@"garry","first_name")
```